# How can I record,pause and keep recording with Matlab functions?

Tags: matlab, audio-recording, playback

I am trying to record, pause, and record again an audio with this code, but it doesn't work true and only the last time I push the record, the sound recorded and before efforts lose.

How should I use pause and resume function to make a record/pause button?

```
function Rec_Pausb_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
global openS recS;
openS=0; recS=1;
handles.recs=str2double(get(handles.Samplef, 'String'));
recb=str2double(get(handles.BPS, 'String'));

if(handles.Samplef >32 || handles.Samplef <8)
    disp('Frequency must between 8 to 32 (KiloHertz)');
else
   handles.Samplef=handles.Samplef;
end
disp(handles.Samplef);

state=get(hObject,'value');
handles.rec=audiorecorder(handles.recs*1000,recb,1);

if state
    set(hObject,'String','Pause');
    resume(handles.rec);
else
    set(hObject,'String','Record');
    pause(handles.rec);


end


guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: If you notice that each result except the last one is discarded, you could perhaps save the result so far when pausing? (and later combine all the pieces)

Comment: Can you explain it by code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the code you have posted above is what is happening in the callback function of the button?

Then a possible explanation could be, that the handles, and thus the handles.rec object, is not updated when the callback exits, and therefore the audio data is not saved. Try to add a `guidata(hObject, handles);` to the end of the callback in order to save the handles.

What version of Matlab are you using? The graphics system was updated in 2014b, so if you are using this version, the above solution might not be applicable.

EDIT: 
Okay, when looking at your complete code, you're initializing the audiorecorder object in the callback, effectively resetting it each time the button is pressed. This means that you start recording all over again whenever you push the button.

You can avoid this by initializing the recorder somewhere outside of the callback, and then pass the object to the button callback function.

Comment: I posted the complete code of the record/pause button!
My matlab's version is R2012a, shall i update it?

Comment: I've updated my answer above, after you've included your complete code.
There should be no need to update, what you are trying to achieve is definitely possible in R2012a as well.

Comment: Thank alooot!
The problem solved very easy! two days I was back of this problem!!

Comment: I wish I could give you reputation but I can't for my not enough reputation :(

Comment: It's okay, glad it helped :-)